# React state : update an index of array objects without explicitly specifying keys

Tags: reactjs, state, spread-syntax

I have an array of objects in my state. I want to update the last object in array. But I don't want to explicitly mention the keys when updating the object.

This is how my code looks right now.

```
import React from 'react'
import update from 'immutability-helper'

class Container extends React.Component {
  state = { queue: [
    {title: 'title 1', message: 'message 1', dismissible: false},
    {title: 'title 2', message: 'message 2', dismissible: true},
    {title: 'title 3', message: 'message 3', dismissible: false},
  ] }
  updateLast = (contents) => {
    this.setState({
      queue: update(this.state.queue, {
        [this.state.queue.length-1]: {
          title: {$set: contents.title},
          message: {$set: contents.message},
          dismissible: {$set: contents.dismissible},
        },
      }),
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="notifications">
        {this.state.queue.map((notification, key) => (
          <Notification key={key} {...notification} />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

As you can see, in the `update` method I am specifying the object keys `title`, `message` etc. explicitly.
Is there some way I can update all the keys of the object using `map` or `spread ...` operator?

Comment: what do you mean by `keys`? Is that a property inside the `queue` object?

Comment: @Thinker `queue` is an array of objects. They keys are the object properties. I am updating my question with the contents of `queue`..

Comment: @vikramalhotra may I know the reason of changing the key of the object? The key is a unique ID (from my understanding), so how you want to edit the key and why do you want to edit it?

Comment: @Thinker oh no. I don't want to change the keys. I want to update the values. But I don't want to use the keys explicitly to update the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `contents` object has the same shape as the items in your array, you could probably add in the object directly. You can remove the last index with `.slice(0, -1)`, then use `.concat` to add the new item to the end. Also to make sure to use the callback form of `setState`, and always do so when the new state depends on the previous in some way.

```
this.setState((state) => ({
  queue: state.queue.slice(0, -1).concat(contents),
}))
```

Array spread works here as well.

```
this.setState((state) => ({
  queue: [...state.queue.slice(0, -1), contents],
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the spread operator, you could slice off the last item in the array and then create a new object to take its place like so:

```
updateLast = (contents) => {
  this.setState({
    queue: [...this.state.queue.slice(0, -1), {
      title: {$set: contents.title},
      message: {$set: contents.message},
      dismissible: {$set: contents.dismissible},
    }],
  })
}
```

Comment: Alright. Your answer was pretty close to the accepted answer. :)

Comment: ah, didn't see all of the `$set` stuff in there; could have just been `contents` like the other answer said.